# Deployment problem with GitHub CI/CD and PowerShell

Tags: powershell, github-actions

I have the following problem when uploading the code to a self-hosted Windows Server 2019 machine, everything happens perfectly until the last step, which is to run the application through a PowerShell script, the application starts momentarily and shuts down. When I type the script in PowerShell, it works perfectly and does not shut down. Manually when I run it with a click *exe also works fine, this problem happened with CI/CD deployment

I try this scripts:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Wialonfuelbackend\WialonCar.exe" -ArgumentList "C:\temp\TestProject1\TestProject1.pjs", "/run", "/exit", "/SilentMode"
```

also this:

```
$procforstarting = @{
    FilePath = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Wialonfuelbackend\WialonCar.exe"
  }
  Start-Process @procforstarting
```

but result is same and below is my full yml

```yaml
 name: Deploy .NET Core Console App

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - name: Output event data
        run: echo "{{ toJSON(github.event) }}"

      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Build and Publish
        run: |
          dotnet build --configuration Release
          dotnet publish --configuration Release --output ./publish

  CheckingServerFile:
    needs: build
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - name: Stop Application If Running
        run: |
          $procforchecking = Get-Process -Name "WialonCar"
          if ($procforchecking -ne $null) {
            Stop-Process -InputObject $procforchecking -Force
          }
      - name: Check if Directory is Empty
        run: |
          $remotePath = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Wialonfuelbackend"  # Define $remotePath here
          $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $remotePath
          if ($files.Length -eq 0) {
            Write-Host "The directory is already empty. Continuing with deployment."
          } else {
            Write-Host "Removing old files..."
            Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -Path $remotePath\*
          }

  deploy:
    needs: CheckingServerFile
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - name: Deploy Console App
        run: |
          $appPath = ".\publish"
          $remotePath = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Wialonfuelbackend"  # Define $remotePath here
          # Add error handling if needed
          xcopy /s /y $appPath\* $remotePath
  
  RunApplication:
    needs: deploy
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - name: Run Console App
        if: success()
        run: |
          Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Wialonfuelbackend\WialonCar.exe" -ArgumentList "C:\temp\TestProject1\TestProject1.pjs", "/run", "/exit", "/SilentMode"
      - name: Run Console App on Failure
        if: failure()
        run: Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -Path "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Wialonfuelbackend\*"
```

Comment: From your description, it sounds like you deploy that executable on the self-hosted runner itself and then start it. So, what you're looking for is to start the process in the background in detached mode. You may find SO threads on this. However, I'd suggest creating a service for this and then you can start/stop/restart/... the service itself as needed.

Comment: Is there an error message in the workflow run logs? Does the application have logging enabled? What do the application logs say?

Comment: i try to adding  this
$process = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Wialonfuelbackend\WialonCar.exe", "C:\temp\TestProject1\TestProject1.pjs /run /exit /SilentMode")
  $process.WaitForExit()
  $exitCode = $process.ExitCode



and application work fine no one exception throw but action not ending because it's still waiting ,another side when i don't have wait what i say previously suddenly shut down


also i modify post and cann see full yml